# Jenkins update builder shell command using groovy

Tags: jenkins, groovy, hudson, jenkins-groovy

I need to update 'execute shell' command of Build section in Series of Jenkins Jobs. And i am using groovy for it.
Here is starting script. Although it does not seems to update.

```
import hudson.model.*

for(item in Hudson.instance.items) {
    if (item.name == 'TEMP-RELEASE-UPDATE') {
        println("--- Parameters for :" + item.name)
        def branches = item.scm.getBranches()
        for (builder in item.buildersList) {
            new_command =  builder.command.replaceAll('PATTERN_1','PATTERN_2')
            builder.command = new_command
            builder.save()
        }
    }
}
```

It normally breaks at 'builder.command = new_command'.
Can someone help to modify this script and save resultant to 'execute shell' block successfully?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

`builder.command = new_command` breaks because builder.command is read-only.

What you need to do is to instantiate new builder instance:

```
new hudson.tasks.Shell(new_command)
```

add that to the list and remove the old one.

My full script:

```
jobsChanged = new java.util.ArrayList()
jobsNotChanged = new java.util.ArrayList()

for(project in Hudson.instance.items) {
  new_builder = null
  old_builder = null
  for (builder in project.buildersList) {
    if (!(builder instanceof hudson.tasks.Shell)) {
      jobsNotChanged.add "$project.name"
      continue;
    }
    new_command = builder.command.replace(SOMETHING, SOMETHINGELSE)

    new_builder = new hudson.tasks.Shell(new_command)
    old_builder = builder;
    jobsChanged.add "$project.name"
  }
  if (new_builder != null) {
    // comment out below for test run
    project.buildersList.add(new_builder)
    project.buildersList.remove(old_builder)
  }

}

println ""
println "Jobs changed"
println ""

jobsChanged.each { line -> println line }

println ""
println "Jobs not changed"
println ""

jobsNotChanged.each { line -> println line }

println ""

""
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [Jenkins Configuration Slicer](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Configuration+Slicing+Plugin) to edit the Shell command of jobs in bulk.

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the job for it to actually be saved.

in your case it would be:

```
item.save()
```